# bash pactl suspend specific application

Tags: linux, bash, audio, sh, suspend

I wrote the following code to suspend the audio of a specific application

```
spotify > '/home/user/Desktop/temp_spotify.txt' 2>&1 & # store terminal output to text file
while :
do # tail grabs recently updated last line in text file | awk searches for specific word in text and then signals exit to tail
  tail -fn0 --pid=$(pidof awk) '/home/user/Desktop/temp_spotify.txt' | awk '/spotify:ad/ { exit }'
  sleep 5
  pactl suspend-sink 2 1 # supend all audio applications grouped under sink 2
  sleep 25
  pactl suspend-sink 2 0 # resume all audio applications grouped under sink 2
done
```

however I was unable to specify a unique identifier for pactl to suspend the spotify application. Instead I specified sink 2, which encompasses many applications.

How does one suspend audio for a specific application?

### Initial Parameters in Text File of Application

```
01:06:27.735 I [breakpad.cpp:110                ] Registered Breakpad for product: spotify

01:06:27.738 I [translate.cpp:152               ] Reloading language file
01:06:27.749 I [translate.cpp:152               ] Reloading language file
01:06:27.750 I [breakpad.cpp:269                ] Searching for crashdumps: /home/user/.cache/spotify/*.dmp

Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6gUEyklNpI,guid=ad6f12cdc093618710fd017755a787fd" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6gUEyklNpI,guid=ad6f12cdc093618710fd017755a787fd" 
Registered DEC:  true 
01:06:27.937 E [offline_key_store.cpp:77        ] Offline: failed to load key stores, error 7007, path /home/user/.cache/spotify/Users/user-user/offline2
01:06:27.940 E [offline_key_store.cpp:77        ] Offline: failed to load key stores, error 7007, path /home/user/.cache/spotify/Users/user-user/cached
```

Comment: You can give a symbolic name instead of the index number. Does the application give a name to its sink?

Comment: @Barmar Using the command pactl list sink-inputs it tells me its in "Sink Input #42"

Comment: @Barmar media.name = "Spotify"
  application.name = "Spotify"

Comment: So try `pactl suspend-sink Spotify 1`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that command before. It returns Failure: No such entity
.

Comment: Does the output in `temp_spotify.txt` contain the name or index of its sink?

Comment: @Barmar I posted the first 11 lines of the text file. All other lines are referenced calls for cpp scripts. The only identifier that pops out is the bus line.